# Is this a good way to track current site being reported on?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm trying to find an elegant and secure way to track the currently reported site. I originally just used a cookie but realized this was not very secure. I have since switched to combine the session and the cookie. It still feels a bit clumsy. Am I missing something here as far as best practices? Can this be improved on?

```
public static int SiteID
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session[SITE_ID_KEY] == null)
                {
                    if (Web.CookieUtil.CookieExists(SITE_ID_KEY))
                    {
                        Guid userId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
                        int siteId = Convert.ToInt32(Web.CookieUtil.GetCookieValue(SITE_ID_KEY));
                        if (Sites.ValidateSite(StateManager.AccountID.Value, siteId, userId))
                        {
                            HttpContext.Current.Session[SITE_ID_KEY] = siteId;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Web.CookieUtil.DeleteCookie(SITE_ID_KEY);
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }

                return (int)HttpContext.Current.Session[SITE_ID_KEY];
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[SITE_ID_KEY] = value;
                Web.CookieUtil.CreateCookie(SITE_ID_KEY, value.ToString(), null);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand, what does “currently reported site” mean? How are you going to use the value? How do you set it in the first place?

Comment: Also, I don't think your question belongs here, since you're not actually asking for code review.

Comment: I am asking for a code review. I have a working solution here and I'm asking for it to be critiqued. The title had to somewhat describe what I'm asking about or trying to accomplish.

Comment: By current site I mean i need to track the current user's website that I am reporting on. I use a site id to track it. I didn't want the user trying to change the cookie and getting some else's data.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what you mean. Are you saying that each user has some websites, can select “current” website from among them and you want to track this selection? Keep in mind you didn't tell us anything about what your application does.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The user can select from among their sites. That site id is what is used to look up their data in the database.

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out, relying on cookies means that the user can choose someone else's site. That means you should not use cookies at all, not even in addition to the session. If you choose to use cookies anyway, you have to validate that the current user actually has access to the selected site before returning any data (or even worse, before performing some action), which your code already does. You also have to be very careful that there isn't any code path that doesn't perform the validation.

Because of this, I think you should store the data in session only. If you need more persistent storage, use your database, not cookies.

---

Some points about your code:

```
return -1;
```

You shouldn't use “magic” values like -1 to indicate “no value”. Instead, change the return type to `int?` and return `null` of no site is selected.

```
Convert.ToInt32(…)
value.ToString()
```

This may not work well unless you're 100 % sure that all servers running this code will be on the same culture. You should probably use `InvariantCulture` here.

Also, if the cookie contains garbage, I think your code should return “no value” not throw an exception.

Comment: Yeah I thought about switching it to nullable int when I saw it and need to do that I guess. I'll look into the culture thing. I was unaware of that. Not sure how I could eliminate the cookies altogether because the cookie is set from the main website before the app loads but I will give it some thought. Thanks!